# Debian is ruining my pc

Tags: debian

So a long time ago i dual booted my windows 10 pc with Debian. I don’t know why I did this but it was stupid. Recently my pc out of who knows where started up and all I saw was grub rescue whatever that means. Now I spent hours in the bios making my pc start with windows and then randomly it starts to blue screen every once in a while. Like one day it will happen 10 times the next it won’t happen at all. So I factory restored hoping that would fix everything. Well my of still crashes and it’s even worse. Almost every time I restart my pc it goes into grub rescue so then I have to go into the bios and change the loading OS from Debian to Windows. I tried to delete Debian in disk manager but won’t work. I’ve looked up how to fix blue screen in but won’t work.

Comment: What is the error message on the blue screen? What do the blue screen logs say? It's highly unlikely Debian is the source of your problems.

Answer (score 4):

Stackexchange is not a user helpdesk forum. This question is probably going to be deleted.

For the sake of helping one in need, I still give you this advice (this is a wild guess, though):
Check your storage device (the hard-disk or SSD your system is trying to boot from).
From my experience, the issues you describe are not caused by a Debian installation, but rather hint to a problem with the disk. Surprisingly often, it is caused by a loose S-ATA connector. Replace the cable if you have one at hand. Same goes for the power plug. Use another one (your power supply should offer more than one). Of course, your disk itself can be faulty. In case you can gain access to Debian, gsmartcontrol offers non-descructive online testing. On Windows, you may try the SMART functions of SpeedFan.